# Unable to use store.subscribe() method in Vuex

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm simply trying to use the `store.subscribe()` method in `Vuex`. I keep getting the following error, which seems to suggest that there is no store.subscribe method, contrary to what is in the docs:

> Uncaught TypeError: **WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__store**.a.state.subscribe is not a function

this is my code:

`app.js` file, where I initialise everything, register my components etc:

```js
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import router from './routes';
import store from './store';

window.Vue = require('vue');

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store: new Vuex.Store(store)
});
store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  console.log(mutation.type)
  console.log(mutation.payload)
})
```

my `store.js` file, which serves as my centralized `Vuex` store. It's been working perfectly until now:

```js
import router from './routes';
export default {
    state: {
      sample: {
        
      }
    },  
    mutations: {
      sample(state){
        
      }
        
    },

    getters: {
      sample(state){
        return state.sample
      }
    }
  
}
```

how do i correct this issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this happens because `store` is still just a regular object and not an instance of `Vuex` yet when you call it.
Can you try the following:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import router from './routes';
import store from './store';

window.Vue = require('vue');
const myStore = new Vuex.Store(store)
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    store: myStore
});
myStore.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
  console.log(mutation.type)
  console.log(mutation.payload)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `app` object like `app.store...` because your `store` is not known as Vuex store instance at that level.

```
    import Vuex from 'vuex';
    import router from './routes';
    import store from './store';

     window.Vue = require('vue');

     const app = new Vue({
         el: '#app',
         router,
         store: new Vuex.Store(store)
       });
     app.$store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
        console.log(mutation.type)
        console.log(mutation.payload)
       })
```